# Access to a variable, which is output from an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

I have a problem with this snippet:

```
d3.csv("data/airports.csv", function(err, a) {
    var count=0;

    a.forEach(function(i){
       if(i.iata_faa == ""){}
       else {
             count++;
             addpoint(i.lon, i.lat,i);
      }
    });

    airports=a;
    myDataIsReady();
    console.log(count);
});

function myDataIsReady(){
    console.log(airports);
    return airports;
}

console.log(airports);
```

Notice that `airports` is a global variable here.

I need to handle the variable `airports` for another function, but the value is null, I think that is null because the csv file has not yet been processed completely, right?

How I resolve it?

Comment: Debug and step through the code. What is the value of `a`? Is `airports` global? Bad, if it is.

Comment: I need it as global because I want to access it from different functions without to load it every time..

Comment: My point is it does not _need_ to be global. Global variables are bad practice. You can simply pass the data by reference or value to other functions.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I plan to have some interaction, and that variable has to be accessed everytime an interaction is triggered. 

You feel I should re-load it at every interaction attempt?

Comment: No. You can wrap all of your functionality that requires use of that variable into an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) or modularize your scripts and use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: What is the value of `a` when you debug your code?

Comment: Why not modularize your code and once your csv is parsed call the functions you need, I don't see the point of having a global variable at this point. Globals are not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for async functions, you push a callback (a function reference) into the async method, so that it processes the data when the ajax call completes.  You don't return data from that type function, you inject data into it.

Comment: or you can use promises

Comment: can you show me how to do it here moreless?

Comment: The last line `console.log(airports);` needs to be removed.  It won't do anything.  Then you might want to push your data to your event handler like `myDataIsReady(airports)`.  Basically, when the event is triggered, pass it the data it needs to do the job.